# Edit files trough sftp Django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

First of all I'm new to Django. I have just installed Django using Digitalocean Ubuntu 16.04. So i started with writing my first Django app using this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/

After editing some files I'm starting to realize that it is not very practical to use ssh for editing files. So i want to use SFTP. I saw in the documentation that their is a Django user with a password. But, because this is not to secure to use a password to login, I created a new user with sudo privileges and added a ssh-key to it.

So when I logged-in as my new user using SFTP and editing a file I figured out that i cannot save files. I'm getting this error: Unable to save file: Permission denied

So then I tried it with the Django user, same results: Unable to save file: Permission denied

Then I tried it as root and successful.

But I Don't want to change files through root but as my new user name. All the files are owned by Django user and the permissions of files and folders are 644 and 755.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't edit files remotely *at all*, either through SFTP or SSH. You should edit locally, commit to version control, then push to your server from there.

Comment: I can't if i'm using digitalocean so that sounds a little weird. Or should I create it locally and when it is finished move it to Digitalocean?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what you should do.